# Passing a count from a relationship on a simple page in Laravel

Tags: laravel, variables, laravel-5, count

I was curious if it was possible to pass along a count of a relationship from a controller and put it on a simple page like a home page (which isn't specifically related to any specific model or controller). So say a user hasMany shipments, how can I pass along the count to the page?

I know how to pass along variables to model specific pages (such as show, edit, index and such pages), but not a general pages such as a home page or about page.

Comment: what is the difference, why does the homepage make it different?

Comment: Well I'm just sure how to pass along a variable without using a controller because the home page is just there, I don't think I've found anywhere in Laravel (yet) that shows me how to pass along specific variables to the home page.

Comment: there is nothing special about the 'homepage', it is just another route like any other, you know how to return views, you know how to pass variables to views

Comment: Well I've passed variables through controllers, but I'm not entirely certain how to pass a variable without a controller.

Comment: Give some example. Which controller method is calling the home view? You should pass it from there.

Comment: you have lost me .. paste up the code you have

Answer (score 0):

You should at least have a PageController and have a method like homepage like this.

```
 class PageController extends Controller {

      protected $data = array();

      public function homepage() {
           $this->data['count'] = 10;
           return view('homepage', $this->data);
      }

 }
```

$data is an array of all the data you would like to pass to your views. As for this example, you can access them in your blade template like this:

```
 {{ $count }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can enable cache in laravel. It is very simple and usefull. You can store your variable in this cache.

For more information, you could read [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/cache#storing-items-in-the-cache)